# Deleting records in MS Access database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Is it possible to delete a record of data and its ID in a Ms Access database entered by the user through a VB application without using Sql commands in VB?

For example,
- if I delete the data from a record with the first ID
- then run the VB app again, I need the user input to be filled into the record with the first ID since it's empty
but in my case it creates a new ID (next record).

Comment: I think he's asking if he can re-use autonumber IDs, and I'm interested in how to do that without SQL also--please elaborate iceDragon.

Comment: @iceDragon, I edited my post after your comment, felt it wasn't clear enough. So, Dan's is suggestion is exactly what am looking for in my access database.